# Did R. Moshe Feinstein misquote the Mishna Berura?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, eating, mishnah-berurah, moshe-feinstein

The Mishna Berura ([299:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.299.1?lang=bi)) rules that one may begin eating until one half hour before tzeis hakochavim on Shabbos afternoon/evening.

R. Moshe Feinstein ([Igros Moshe O.C. 4:69:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=129&hilite=)) writes that the Mishna Berura was only lenient in a case where the person had not yet eaten the third meal.

> ורק שהמ"ב אינו מיקל אלא בלא אכל סעודה שלישית ולא לשתות יין

However, the Mishna Berura actually explicitly states that this ruling applies even for other eating.

> ואפילו לשאר אכילה אם הוא תאב לאכול ולשתות ג"כ אין להחמיר עד חצי שעה
>   שקודם צה"כ

How is this to be explained? Or what sources (if any) note this problem?

Comment: I think hes just saying that the MB holds that you **should** start S"S at that time, but if you've already eaten, to join just for the sake of a Zimun would likely be prohibited according to even the M"B, and that would be the mistake of the mezamnin.  Good Q, as usual!

Comment: Does the MB permit all eating or just if you are really really hungry?

Comment: @DoubleAA "אם הוא תאב לאכול" sounds like there needs to be a certain threshold of hunger.

Comment: Ok so that answers the question then. R Moshe's case didn't involve someone who was really hungry.

Comment: @DoubleAA The question was not about reconciling the rulings of R. Moshe and the MishnaBerura. I grant from the outset that R. Moshe disagrees with the MishnaBerura's  leniency (as he says "שתמוה לי דבר זה"). My question is only on how he quotes the MishnaBerura – "אינו מיקל אלא בלא אכל סעודה שלישית" vs what the Mishna Berura actually says – "ואפילו לשאר אכילה אם הוא תאב לאכול ולשתות", implying that the Mishna Berura would agree that תאב לאכול ולשתות is not a valid reason to eat). It is possible that he wasn't so precise in his quote, but on the face of it the quote certainly seems inaccurate.

Comment: I think RMF is referring to the Biur Halocho ibid. The Biur Halocho - https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.299.1?lang=bi&p2=Biur_Halacha.299.1.1&lang2=bi -  seems to be leaning towards RMF and maybe even stricter. Unclear - from a speed-read - how he got to his Kula in the M.B.

Comment: The distinction between the language in Mishnah Berurah and Reb Moshe is that Reb Moshe is pointing out the leniency of the Mishnah Berurah is only if one has not eaten the 3rd meal of Shabbat. If one simply desires to drink wine after one has finished the 3rd meal, it is prohibited. If one has not had the 3rd meal and wants bread and wine together, it is fine. A related idea is that one can fulfill the mitzvah of the 3rd meal with fruit if they aren't really hungry.

Comment: @DannySchoemann for what it's worth, I think it's Be'ur Halacha, not Biur. With a tzeirei, not a chirik